# Accessing snowflake file system

Tags: amazon-web-services, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am new to snowflake and I have two questions regarding Snowflake on AWS.

1. I registered for a free account of Snowflake and It gave me a link to access its web UI and thereafter I could create a stage in WebUI using my exist AWS S3 bucket , however after loading of data , I am not sure , where  does snowflake stores the data. Can I access its file system? Can I change its file system to my existing AWS S3?
2. While registration of Snowflake on AWS , I went to AWS Marketplace and Subscribed to snowflake account and it gave a snowflake webUI. Do I need to do anything else for deployment of Snowflake on AWS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The data you imported from S3 into Snowflake now resides in a logical database table.  The database stores its data in its own S3 bucket.  The database storage format is proprietary, and a database abstract storage layer S3 bucket possibly contains data from multiple customers.  The data is encrypted, and in the end Snowflake probably doesn't even know eg. which disk the data is on, they are S3 users like everyone else.
2. You can do almost anything from the GUI.  But the GUI doesn't provide a proper archive for code and object history etc.  Snowflake has recently acquired a company with a development tool, so maybe something more than the GUI is in the coming.

Comment: Get to know more by reading https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/intro-key-concepts.html

Comment: Thanks Hans for the answer

Comment: So , It means from your answer , It looks that We can not change the underlying file system for snowflake to our own AWS S3  and For installation  of snowflake , It just registration of account with the cloud platform.

Comment: Well, you have the Entreprise Virtual Private Cloud edition of Snowflake, but it is still bound by the cloud plattform. You can't install Snowflake yourself.

Comment: But then again, why would you want to do that? What are the requirements that makes you want to forfeit the near-zero admin benefits you get from Software as a Service?

Comment: As Snowflake stores the data in its own storage layer , so how will be security of client data is maintained. As of this concern , my client wants to store data in client managed cloud

Comment: The customer can only manage staging areas, but not the table store.  All data is encrypted at permanent locations, and the Snowflake VPC edition lets customers encrypt the data with a customer managed master key.  Data encryption is described in https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/security-encryption.html